Flutter TextField stops other Widgets from showing up?
I'm trying to learn Flutter by building a toy example.
Whenever I add my TextField into this basic example, none of the other Widgets show up. The Layout Explorer in VS Code doesn't show the layout anymore, and I don't see any error logs.
Two questions:
1) How I can debug what I've done wrong? I want to learn for next time.
2) What have I done wrong?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageFive extends StatefulWidget
{
  const PageFive({super.key});

 @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState()
  {
    return PageFiveState();
  } 
}

class PageFiveState extends State
{
  TextEditingController tfc = TextEditingController();
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200] ,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("This is light red"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red[300]),
          body: Row (
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                  Text("one"),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                  TextField( // If I comment out this widget, everything else shows up
                    controller: tfc,
                    onChanged: textFieldChangedCallback,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "This is the label",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                      hintText: 'Write something here',
                    ),
                  ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                Text("tfc.value.text"), // yes, I know to lose the quotes. This just made it easier to comment stuff out for now.
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                  Text("two"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

void textFieldChangedCallback(String newValue)
{
  setState(() {
  });
}

}


It seems if I take out the Row and the second Column, the Textfield shows up and allows the other widgets to show up... but when I type in the TextField, it only allows one character. What have I done? :-)

Okay, this has something to do with unbounded widgets in width or height. I don't know how to figure out which ones though.

Error: An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
Solution: Wrap both your columns inside Expanded or Flexible.
Since TextField causes the unbounded width issue with Row, wrapping parent widget of TextField (in this case Column) with above widgets should solve the issue.
You can wrap only one Column which has TextField, but wrapping another Column make both Column same width.
